# The type or namespace name 'CDO' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to parse through some .eml files and ran into this problem. I'm very new to ASP.NET and need help figuring this out.`

```
 var fileName = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("ddMMMyyyy"); //yesterday's date 
        //var fileName = "28Aug2018"; //yesterday's date

        var id = Request.QueryString["id"]; //id for file to access from url
        //Response.Write(fileName);
        String emlFile = "E:/Spam/" + fileName + "/" + id + ".eml";
        var eml = ReadMessage(emlFile);
        Response.Write(eml.To); 
        Response.Write("<br/>");
        Response.Write(eml.From);
        Response.Write("<br/>");
        Response.Write(eml.Subject); 
        Response.Write("<br/>");
        Response.Write(eml.TextBody);
```

This is where I call the function on page load

```
protected CDO.Message ReadMessage(String emlFileName)
    {
        CDO.Message msg = new CDO.MessageClass();
        ADODB.Stream stream = new ADODB.StreamClass();
        stream.Open(Type.Missing,
                       ADODB.ConnectModeEnum.adModeUnknown,
                       ADODB.StreamOpenOptionsEnum.adOpenStreamUnspecified,
                       String.Empty,
                       String.Empty);
        stream.LoadFromFile(emlFileName);
        stream.Flush();
        msg.DataSource.OpenObject(stream, "_Stream");
        msg.DataSource.Save();
        return msg;
    }
```

And this is the code to parse the .eml files. The code works fine locally but I get the error when I run it online. Searched a lot for the issue but couldn't figure out a solution.

Comment: It seems like the expected assembly containing the types below `CDO` did not load correctly. Is it a 3th party library? Could you check the library version loaded by the online server? Maybe the fusion logs will give you some insight. Or bind to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event to see if it returns null for the specified assembly.

Comment: Isn't CDO a really old ActiveX component for dealing with emails? Pretty sure I've not used that for 15 years when I was doing classic ASP.

Comment: @DavidG What would you recommend for parsing .eml files then? I'm new to this. I found CDO method here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a good answer here. Why do you even have eml files? What information are you trying to extract from them?

Comment: You might have some joy with this Nuget package instead https://www.nuget.org/packages/Independentsoft.Msg/

Comment: @DavidG I got the same error using the Nugate package as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be the location of the bin folder in my case.
My bin folder was located in ...wwwroot/Project_name/Project_name.
I copied the bin folder to wwwroot and it worked fine after that.